# Python 3 - optparse - how to change return value when error occurs

Tags: python, error-handling, python-3.x

I have o problem with return value of optparse. When script find an unknown argument it exites with error message and return value 2 (echo $?).

I need to have 1 returned and also I want to set my own error mesage, how can I do that?

Here is a part of code:

```
import sys
import re
import ast 
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser(usage="usage: %prog [OPTIONS] ", version="%prog 1.0")

parser.add_option("", "--input",
              action="store", 
              dest="inputfile",
              default="stdin",
              help="Allow to set an input file. Default input is STDIN.")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
options_dictionary = vars(options)
```

Comment: ok after day I found this solution. Im still not sure that it's the best one, but it works for me.

    try:
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    except SystemExit:
        print("Error: špatné vstupní parametry, začněte prosím s -    h.",file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

Answer (score 0):

ok after day I found this solution. Im still not sure that it's the best one, but it works for me.

```
try:
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
except SystemExit:
    print("Error: špatné vstupní parametry, začněte prosím s -h.",file=sys.stderr)
sys.exit(1)
```